# Using trapz and linspace to evaluate an integral in Matlab

Tags: integration, matlab

I have two functions f(x) and g(x), and I need to find a numerical approximation to the area bounded by the two curves.

How do I do this using the `trapz` and `linspace` functions?

Thanks

Comment: f(x) = sin(x)-g(x) in your example, not two separate functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose I want to integrate over $[0 ,2\pi]$, and divide that into $1000$ subintervals.

To do this, first create a vector for the interval:

> >>X = `linspace`(0,2*pi,1000);

Then create a vector containing the function values you want to integrate. If $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = x^2$ then the area between them is equal to the integral of *their difference*, and I would use

> >>Y = sin(X) - X.^2;

finally, integrate

> >>my_answer = trapz(X,Y);

Or, if you want it to display the answer, you can omit the semi-colon. e.g.

> >>my_answer = trapz(X,Y)
>
> ans = -82.6834

or if you don't even care about storing the value (only displaying it)

> >>trapz(X,Y)
>
> ans = -82.6834

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but thanks a lot! I didn't quite understand the concept of linspace and precisely what the first argument of the trapz function needed to be, but you answered both those questions for me :)